# Plot just the top line in a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a `matplotlib` plot that plots multiple (about 4-5) different histograms in the same figure. However, to prevent it from getting too crowded, I would like to plot the same histograms but with just the top horizontal line (so it would look like a `plt.plot()` continuous line but made of lots of steps). How can I do it?

Comment: Give us example data and plot.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword argument `plt.hist(data,histtype='step')`.
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html